# How to get Difference between two datetime?

Tags: database, oracle

I want to get difference between two datetime in minutes. I have attached picture of my data stored in table and datatype of my columns is Varchar2. I have created below query and I am getting error of "Not a valid month". what I want that when user_closer_date column is null then I want to add default sysdate.

```
SELECT ROUND(60*24*(COALESCE(TO_DATE(lse.user_closer_date , 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), sysdate) - to_date(Request_Raised_Date
  ||' '
  ||request_raised_time, 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'))) AS TAT
  FROM sml.Xx_Lsp_Linestoppage_Entry lse 
  Left join Emp_Master cm ON Lse.Raised_By = Cm.Emp_No
  Left join Emp_Master cm1 ON Lse.Closer_User = Cm1.Emp_No
  Left join Emp_Master cm2 ON Lse.Final_Closed_By = Cm2.Emp_No
  where Lse.Request_Raised_Date Between To_Date('01-Jan-2022', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') and To_Date('28-Feb-2022', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
  ORDER BY lse.Line_Stop_Id Asc;
```

[image]

Comment: What are the data types of `user_closer_date` and `Request_Raised_Date`?

Comment: From your comment, it seems that request_raised_date is varchar2. In the WHERE clause, you are comparing it to dates. So the DB is doing the conversion, using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT. Check what you have there. Also, it is a very bad practice to store dates in an oracle db in varchar2 format. Use DATE or TIMESTAMP for that.

Comment: Colums is Varchare2  type

Comment: keeping date/time in a varchar2 (or any other string datatype) is a fundamental design flaw, and your problem is a direct result of that flaw.  Use the correct data types and your problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is exactly how it's done, only the datatypes should be DATE as @EdStevens said, which contains both day and time. Conventionally, your task would be done like that:

```
CREATE TABLE lse (
  request_raised DATE,
  user_closer    DATE
);
INSERT INTO lse VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 09:20:00', NULL);
INSERT INTO lse VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 08:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 08:15:00');
INSERT INTO lse VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 06:34:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 06:50:00');
INSERT INTO lse VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 06:36:00', NULL);
```

Then your query just works:

```
SELECT ROUND(60*24* (COALESCE(user_closer, SYSDATE) - request_raised))
  FROM lse 
 WHERE request_raised BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00' 
                          AND TIMESTAMP '2022-02-28 23:59:59';

666
15
16
830
```

BTW, you can use of course `TO_DATE('2022-Feb-11 09:20', 'YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI')` instead of the ANSI literal `DATE '2022-02-11 09:20:00', I find the latter just personally shorter and clearer.

In case you are forced to present day and time as string, you can easily convert a DATE to a VARCHAR2, even on the fly with a virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE lse ADD request_raised_date GENERATED ALWAYS AS
  (TO_CHAR(request_raised, 'DD-Mon-YYYY', 'nls_date_language=ENGLISH')) VIRTUAL;

ALTER TABLE lse ADD request_raised_time 
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(request_raised, 'HH24:MI')) VIRTUAL;


SELECT * FROM lse;

REQUEST_RAISED   USER_CLOSER       REQUEST_RAISED_DATE  REQUEST_RAISED_TIME
---------------- ---------------   -------------------  --------------------
2022-02-11 09:20 (null)            11-Feb-2022          09:20
2022-02-11 08:00 2022-02-11 08:15  11-Feb-2022          08:00
2022-02-11 06:34 2022-02-11 06:50  11-Feb-2022          06:34
2022-02-11 06:36 (null)            11-Feb-2022          06:36
```